# Linebreak in overlaid figure text

Tags: graphics, line-breaking

As a simple example, consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \put(-80,20){some text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image: MWE_result]

Primary question: How do I make a linebreak inside `put` such as `some\\ text`?

Secondary questions: What enables the `put` command? Is it something implicitly loaded with `memoir` or `graphicx`? Where do I find the documentation?

I know a similar output can be created using the `overpic` or `tikz` package, which apparently are not necessary for this MWE. Also, `overpic` does not allow for linebreaks either (at least not in the simple `\\` way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "some text" with a `\parbox`.  The `\parbox` will wrap automatically, or linebreaks `\\` can be manually added.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \put(-80,20){\parbox{.5in}{some text}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you could use the same approach with a `\stackinset`, which allows you to specify the inset as an offset from the picture's left, center, right (horizontally) or top, center, bottom (vertically):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \stackinset{c}{.2in}{c}{-.4in}{\parbox{.5in}{some text}}{
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth]{example-image}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As to `\put`, it is part of LaTeX's native `picture` environment.